# how to handle multiple input changes with only 1 handler with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have several states and I would like to write only 1 handler for all of them. On change, only 1 handler will trigger and change the state only if it has changed.

I have the solution for class based components like this

```
handleChange (evt) {
    this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
}
```

But when I use function based components, I couldn't figure it out how.

```
export default function DateBar(props)
{
    let date = new Date();
    let i = 1;
    const days = Array.from({length: new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate()}).map(() => <option key = {uuidv4()} value={i}>{i++}</option>);

    const monthOpts = props.months.map(month => <option key = {uuidv4()} value={month} name = {month} id = {month}>{month}</option>);
    const yearsOpts = props.years.map(year => <option key = {uuidv4()} value ={year} name = {year} id = {year}>{year}</option>);


    // states
    const [today, setToday] = useState("");
    const [thisMonth, setThisMonth] = useState("");
    const [year, setYear] = useState("");

    useEffect(() =>
    { 
        setToday(date.getDate());
        setThisMonth(props.months[date.getMonth()]);
        setYear(date.getYear());
    }, []);

    const handleChange = () => 
{
    // for example, if day is changed, i want to call setToday() somehow..
}

    return(
        <div className="DateBarRoot">
                <FormControl className="formControl input" variant="outlined">
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="today">Day</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                    native
                    value={today}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label = 'day'
                    inputProps={{
                        name: 'today',
                        id: 'today',
                    }}
                    >
                        {days}
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <FormControl className="formControl input" variant="outlined">
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="month">Month</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                    native
                    value={thisMonth}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label = 'month'
                    inputProps={{
                        name: 'thisMonth',
                        id: 'thisMonth',
                    }}
                    >
                        {monthOpts}
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <FormControl variant="outlined" className="formControl input">
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="year">Year</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                    native
                    className="select"
                    value={year}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label = 'year'
                    inputProps={{
                        name: 'year',
                        id: 'year',
                    }}
                    >
                        {yearsOpts}
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>                
            </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a single state item that holds these values. In fact, this is covered by the [`useState` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState` does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:
>
> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState({});
> setState(prevState => {
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```
>
> Another option is `useReducer`, which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple sub-values.

In your case, it might be:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({}); // Or maybe a Map
// ...
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValues(values => {
        return {...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value};
    });
};
```

Or with some destructuring:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({}); // Or maybe a Map
// ...
const handleChange = ({target: {name, value}}) => {
    setValues(values => {
        return {...values, [name]: value};
    });
};
```

Or, as they say above, you can use [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) and, probably, a `switch` on the event target name.

Comment: Since im a beginner, i would like to ask.. Is it a good practice to keep several states in one object? Because as I assume, it would be inefficient to copy back the states that haven't changed.
In addition,  a switch on the event target name would be a solution as you mentioned but I would like to know if there is a kind of a "shortcut" in hooks as we have in class based components.

Comment: @Wokers - It's fine, copying the values doesn't take any time to worry about. Or put it another way, if and when you find a performance problem caused by having done that, fix it then. :-D Note that you'd be making a copy in `useReducer`, too. The alternative is to use discrete state items and a `switch` in the event handler, which is also a perfectly reasonable approach. I tend to take the view that if the values are, conceptually, a single thing and/or I'm indexing dynamically like you are, I'll group them together this way. Otherwise I keep them separate.